# Excel 2010 VBA or formula to find value in dynamic column based off entry (vlookup like) but copy the value and paste the value into the cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

My question is rather complex so I will try to use examples and be clear as possible. In one table I have values that are populated based off formula:

```
Name  Timestamp  Datedif1
123    1-Oct        1     (date dif between today and timestamp, formula based)
```

In another table I want to be able to enter the name and populate some of the information from the first table:

```
Name  Timestamp  Datedif1  Datedif2
123     2-Oct       1         0
```

`Datedif1` being drawn from the first table, `Datedif2` being the new timestamp (entered into the second table and current date).

The problem is, I want to be able to delete the row from the first table after it has copied over `Datedif1`.

Essentially I would like to do a `VLOOKUP()` based off the name, to get `Datedif1`, but have it paste the value of `Datedif1` into the cell versus constantly looking to find the name and relying on the first table to remain populated with the information.

I am pretty sure I need VBA code to do this since formulas will always rely on pointing to cells, and I do not know a formula to copy and paste a static value without referring to another cell.  I am not versed in VBA code but have programmed C a long time ago.

Thanks Eric F for the start.  I think I need to clairfy my desire activity a little more.  What I would like to do is once I manually enter Name in table 2, the Datedif1 value will be copy and pasted from table 1, as a value.  Theory would look like this:
if Name = "", ""
If Name = 123, VLOOKUP(123, table 1, return datedif1(column 3), FALSE)
paste the vlookup as a value so it will not chnage if table 1 gets deleted

Thanks.

Comment: Would this be something you need done once or something you want to be reusable?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have made an example that should help you with this. The data is different but hopefully you can follow it to make your own macro.  I have two sheets like you do. Sheet1 has my initial data. Sheet2 will be my filtered data.

```
Public Sub do_stuff_and_things()
Dim i As Integer
Dim insertrow As Integer
i = 1
Do Until i = Range("'Sheet1'!A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1

 If Range("'Sheet1'!A" & i).Value = "Joe" Then
  If Range("'Sheet1'!B" & i).Value = "2" Then
   'conditions are true so copy to next sheet
   insertrow = Range("'Sheet2'!A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
   Range("'Sheet2'!A" & insertrow & ":D" & insertrow).Value = Range("'Sheet1'!A" & i & ":D" & i).Value
  End If
 End If

i = i + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

Upon running the macro, it will go through sheet1 using the conditions that I specified with my IF statements. If the conditions are true then it will proceed to copy the entire line to the next blank row on Sheet2. I specified the row to be columns A through D but of course change it to yours.

Hope this helps you to get started at least.